# Can not correctly add Urban Airship PhoneGap/Cordova Plugin

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, urbanairship.com, visual-studio-cordova

I need to include [Urban Airship PhoneGap/Cordova Plugin](https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push) to my Visual Studio Cordova project. Visual studio successfully built the *apk* file, and installed it on emulator and went to debug mode. When app is launched, the crash happens and I only see message box saying `The application error occurred`.

I understand that the crash reason is incorrect plugin including. 
Here is the [*confix.xml*, log of building and Visual Studio -built *AndroidManifest.xml* (from \bld\Debug)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LroufH-FyAUfMERvdcc94gvr37XFngdNf0b09nuq30I/edit#gid=1559452498).

Please help correctly include this plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Without crash logs its hard to say. Usually the problem is with the custom_rules.xml file not being deleted in the root of the Phonegap Android project. It prevents libraries that contain resources from being packaged properly.

Comment: "Log of building" this is not crash log?. Visual studio only write "Log of building", or I do not know where to look :) No suggestions how to make this plugin work? I can throw any information....

Comment: If you write into Urban Airship's support they are better equipped at helping. 

Build logs are not the same as the logs running on the device. You can access the logs on the device through adb logcat - http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html. The Android SDK comes with a tool called "monitor" that can be used to access the logs on the device as well - http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monitor.html.